# Return json from controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

How do I return multiple objects using json

```
var result1 = new { stores = this.getstoreResults("param") };
var result2 = new { places = this.getplaceResults("param") };
```

result1 and result2 are two different objects with different properties, how do I combine and return them to a view?

```
return Json(result1+result2); --How?
```

Also, how do I map that in jquery?

```
response($.map(data, function (item) {});
```

Comment: In which language are your objects defined? What about the controller? What do you want to map with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can return a response as an array of objects like:

```
Json(new [] { response1, response2 })
```

on the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) side you can transformt those array of objects in one alone.

```
var oCombined = {}
$.each(oJSONArray,function() 
{ 
    oCombined = $.extend(oCombined, this)
});
```

If you are intended to do a version of "JQuery extend" in the C# side, you could achieve this creating a function that interates via reflection all the properties of the objects and return an ExpandoObject dynamic type (only C# 4+) as a combination result something like:

```
function ExpandoObject Extender(object obj1, Type obj1Type, object obj2, Type obj2Type) 
{
    var result = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    //Property Interator obj1
         result.Add(ob1.PropertyName, ..)

    //Property Interator obj2
         result.Add(ob2.PropertyName, ..)

    return result;
}
```

In the end your code would be:

```
return Json(Extender(result1,result2));
```

Comment: This will return an array in JSON, not a single object.

Comment: Yes, it will be an array of object and this array can be treated to combine the objects in one alone

Answer (score 4):

`return Json(new { result1 = result1, result2 = result2 });`

In js you can use that properties as `var r1 = data.result1;`

Answer (score 1):

If both JSONs are generated from same datatype,
add both to a LIST<> and then convert to JSON using JSON.NET (`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` method)